# Hyperledger Fabric node stops working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am running a `Hyperledger Fabric` node on Ubuntu 16.0.4 deployed on AWS. I have deployed smart contracts (3 participants and 4 assets) and written my own APIs using `nodejs`. The application works great but almost every 7-10 days the application just breaks down and all API calls to the smart contracts (`composer-rest-server` or even my own APIs) fail and throw this error

> Error trying to ping. Error: Error trying to query business network. Error: chaincode error (status 500, message: Error: The current identity, with the name admin and the identifier xxxxxxx, has not been registered

We leave the server running 24*7 and the only way I am able to solve this is by restarting the entire network, including creating a new CA, admin, which results in all my blockchain data being lost.

I need a solution/ understanding as to why this problem pops up, how to solve it, and how to save the Blockchain state when restarting the nodes.

Screenshot from one of our tests with the error highlighted:

[image]

Comment: These stack overflow threads help in the persistence of the data,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45590891/hyperledger-composer-model-not-persisted/45619099#45619099 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48070818/how-to-restart-the-fabric-composer-without-losing-the-existing-data

Comment: This persistence of data is when we turn off a node and restart it. I am already using the method given in the links. Mine is a different issue.